# Value of type 'String?' has no member 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift

Estou com o seguinte problema:

> Value of type 'String?' has no member 'Int'

Qual o motivo do erro e qual a solução?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var happinessField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func add() {
        if nameField == nil || happinessField == nil {
            return
        }

        let name = nameField!.text
        let happiness = happinessField!.text.Int() // Erro aqui
        if happiness == nil {
            return }
        let meal = Meal(name: name!, happiness: happiness!)
        print("eaten: \(meal.name) \(meal.happiness)")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro é porque a estrutura [`String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string) não tem nenhuma função chamada `Int()`. [Veja na documentação oficial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string).

Se estiver usando Swift **1.x**

Deve usar o `toInt()` e não `Int()`.

```
let happines = happinessField!.text.toInt()
```

Ou, a partir do Swift **2.x**

```
let happines = Int(happinessField!.text)
```

Comment: Isso era no Swift 1.0 acho

Answer (score 0):

Nao existe essa funcao que voce esta tentando acessar.

Se voce quer converter um String pra Int, voce precisa usar:

```
let happiness:Int? = Int(happinessField.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para a sua solução eu sugiro utilizar guard let. Assim já previamente fazendo validações de campos vazios e que nao foram possiveis de fazer o cast pro tipo.

```
guard let name =  nameField!.text else { return }    
guard let hapiness =  Int(happinessField!.text) else { return }
```

Isso faz com que as variaveis name e hapiness não sejam opcionais e no caso do hapiness que ele foi feito o cast para Int corretamente.

Refatorando o codigo ficaria dessa forma:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var happinessField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func add() {
        guard let name =  nameField!.text, 
              let hapiness =  Int(happinessField!.text)
              else { return } 

        let meal = Meal(name: name, happiness: happiness)
        print("eaten: \(meal.name) \(meal.happiness)")

    }

}
```